# I'm not able to extract zip file from AWS S3 using .NET Core C#

Tags: c#, .net, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I'm trying to extract/unzip a file from s3 bucket through c# .Net core 6 in lambda environment.
When calling the **ZipArchive** method, I get an exception.

Here is the Exception I get,

> error message: **End of Central Directory record could not be found. and stack trace:**    at System.IO.Compression.ZipArchive.ReadEndOfCentralDirectory()
> at System.IO.Compression.ZipArchive..ctor(Stream stream, ZipArchiveMode mode, Boolean leaveOpen, Encoding entryNameEncoding)
> at System.IO.Compression.ZipArchive..ctor(Stream stream, ZipArchiveMode mode)

Here's the code that I tried,

```cs
using var objResult = await _s3Client.GetObjectAsync(bucket, key);

using var zipArchive = new ZipArchive(objResult.ResponseStream, ZipArchiveMode.Read); **//Exception line**

foreach (ZipArchiveEntry zipEntry in zipArchive.Entries)
{
    var output = new MemoryStream();
    zipEntry.Open().CopyTo(output);

    *** code follows to readline from stream***
}
```

Comment: Welcome. Your code is correct; your ZIP file is most likely corrupted. Please try downloading the file from the console to confirm this. This is a single-part ZIP file correct?

Comment: Side note: whatever it is you are doing, you probably don't need to copy it into a `MemoryStream`. Also `zipEntry.Open()` returns a stream, whihc you need to dispose with `using`.

Comment: The error it refers to in your exception, means that it cannot find the "delimiter" that signals to the zip component, that it has reached the end of the file. 

Much like a CRLF, if the "end-signal" is missing, zip doesn't know if it has the required compressed string to uncompress. 

And thus it throws the exception: 
End of Central Directory record could not be found

You need to either reload the file, or validate that it is not corrupted at source, try to perhaps manually copy the file, and extract it?

Comment: Thank you for your comments on this... FYI @ErmiyaEskandary and MortenBork , I can download and extract the file manually.  I think so, file won't be corrupted.  And that zip file contains only one file(text file in file format) in it.

Comment: I believe then, that the response stream is not being read to it's end, or is using a different encoding type than provided. This would corrupt the central directory also.